# Pyspark can't pickle local object (list of functions)

Tags: python, pyspark, pickle, data-mining, reduce

I'm trying to implement LSH in pyspark, my implementation perfectly works for small sets of documents but, when the set is quite huge, I obtain this error:

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object '__hash_family__.<locals>.hash_member'
```

And then:

```
19/11/21 17:59:40 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<my_home_dir>/PycharmProjects/data_mining/hw_2/ex_3/main_kijiji.py", line 62, in <module>
    lsh = signatures.reduce(lambda x, y: __update_hash_table__(x[0], x[1], lsh_b, lsh_r) +
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 844, in reduce
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 816, in collect
    sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
```

The error is generated by this line of code:

```
lsh = signatures.reduce(lambda x, y: __update_hash_table__(x[0], x[1], hash_tables, lsh_b, lsh_r) +
                                     __update_hash_table__(y[0], y[1], hash_tables, lsh_b, lsh_r)).cache()
```

where *hash_tables* is a list generated in this way:

```
hash_tables = [[__hash_family__(i, lsh_num_hashes), {}] for i in range(lsh_b)]
```

The function *hash_family* is the following:

```
def __hash_family__(i, resultSize=20):
    maxLen = 10  # how long can our i be (in decimal)
    salt = str(i).zfill(maxLen)[-maxLen:]

    def hash_member(x):
        return hashlib.sha1((x + salt).encode()).digest()[-resultSize:]

    return hash_member
```

And this is the function ***update_hash_table***:

```
def __update_hash_table__(doc_id, sig, hash_tables, lsh_b, lsh_r):
    for b in range(lsh_b):
        start_row = b * lsh_r
        end_row = start_row + lsh_r
        band = str(sig[start_row:end_row])
        bucket_idx = hash_tables[b][0](''.join(band))
        try:
            hash_tables[b][1][bucket_idx].append(doc_id)
        except KeyError:
            hash_tables[b][1][bucket_idx] = [doc_id]
    return hash_tables
```

I even tried to generate the *hash_tables* directly in the file that contains the definition of ***update_hash_table*** or to generate the tables inside the function, but I always get the pickling error, how can I rewrite my code to store in the variable ***lsh*** the result of that reduce operation? 
I know I could collect *signatures* and transform it in a list from the rdd, but it would be very expensive, can I still execute this operation without increasing too much the execution time?

Comment: There are limits to what pickle will serialise.  Some googling suggests that most implementations struggle with dynamically defined classes and functions (inc lambdas).  I would take a look at "dill", it seems to build upon pickle to cope with more types.

Comment: `sha1` is a terrible choice as hash function. But with so much python, this never won't be fast anyway. I guess a good C implementation will on a single node outperform your Spark cluster...